# Handling unspecified routes in react-router

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router

I have an Express/React application that uses React Router, and I'm not sure how to handle unspecified routes from the React end of things.

My express configuration calls `app.get('/*', handler)`, which renders `index.html` so that the routing responsibilities are passed off to React. How can I use React Router to handle routes that haven't been predetermined. For example, if I got to `myapp.com/test`, I get the following error:

> Location "/test" did not match any routes

**How can I configure react-router to serve a 404 page, or to redirect to the default route if the URL is unrecognized?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router has a similar directive:

```
<Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404} />
```

This will render component NotFound and ensure 404 status is sent to the client in case you need it for server side rendering - universal/isomorphic apps.

Hope that helps